# Zend clear Request Parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework, parameters, front-controller

I just wanted to ask why the following inside a Zend_Controller_Action action method:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$params = $request->getParams();
var_dump($params);
foreach ($params as $key => &$value) {
    $value = null;
}
var_dump($params);
$request->setParams($params);
var_dump($request->getParams());
```

produces this:

```
array
  'controller' => string 'bug' (length=3)
  'action' => string 'edit' (length=4)
  'id' => string '210' (length=3)
  'module' => string 'default' (length=7)
  'author' => string 'test2' (length=5)

array
  'controller' => null
  'action' => null
  'id' => null
  'module' => null
  'author' => null

array
  'author' => string 'test2' (length=5)
```

Shouldn't the 'author' variable be cleared too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getParams method is shown below. What happens is you're clearing the built in params (controller, action etc...) but the method always returns GET and POST variables.

```
/**
 * Retrieve an array of parameters
 *
 * Retrieves a merged array of parameters, with precedence of userland
 * params (see {@link setParam()}), $_GET, $_POST (i.e., values in the
 * userland params will take precedence over all others).
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getParams()
{
    $return       = $this->_params;
    $paramSources = $this->getParamSources();
    if (in_array('_GET', $paramSources)
        && isset($_GET)
        && is_array($_GET)
    ) {
        $return += $_GET;
    }
    if (in_array('_POST', $paramSources)
        && isset($_POST)
        && is_array($_POST)
    ) {
        $return += $_POST;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: is there something like a clearPost method? setPost does not accept null values :/

Comment: You can use $request->setParamSources(array()); which affects the $paramSources above - if it's set to an empty array, GET and POST data is not retrieved. You may need to set it back to including GET and POST if other code relies on getParams.

Comment: I meant like clearing all POST and GET data in the Request Object. I wrote them myself already, but maybe there is some other way, how things are ment to be done by Zend Developers?

Answer (score 1):

To clear params you can simply call:

```
$request->clearParams();
```